# How do you center align the text of the column headings for a lightning:datatable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, lightning-datatable

I'm able to apply color or make the column heading text bold, but I can't center align the text for some reason.

```
<lightning:datatable data="{! v.data }"
        columns="{! v.columns }"
        keyField="id"
        resizeColumnDisabled="true"
        hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
```

---

```
.THIS table thead th {
   color: red;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

Putting `text-align: center` in the css doesn't seem to have any effect on the column text. Even directly altering the div surrounding the lightning:datatable with a style tag doesn't work.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you try enclosing the `lightning:datatable` in a `div` and giving the `div` a class: `slds-align_absolute-center`

Comment: @Sarang this didn't work. That doesn't seem to affect text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just add css that below this and worked.

for column
.THIS .slds-th__action{ 
justify-content: center !important; 
}

for body
.THIS .slds-grid_align-end {
    justify-content: center !important;
}

Comment: Would you please add more explanation to your answer that would clarify why it worked.

Comment: Sorry Eduard that css for table's body. 
For Column you must add css that below this.
'
.THIS .slds-th__action{
    justify-content: center !important;
}'

Comment: Please, [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/249450/edit) your question and provide details there

Comment: This worked! The column headers centered with `.THIS .slds-th__action{ justify-content: center; }`

Comment: If you want the header to be right-aligned: `.THIS .slds-th__action{ justify-content: flex-end; }`

Comment: This should really be done in the column data if possible, as the data type generally dictates the horizontal alignment.

Comment: You have to place that into your css file and that's it! It works fine!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code :

```
<div  class="myUniqueTable">
    <lightning:datatable aura:id="accountContacts-list"
                         data="{!v.data}"
                         columns="{!v.columns}"
                         keyField="id"
                         maxRowSelection="1"
                         selectedRows="{!v.selectedIds}" />
</div>
```

and in css add this:

```
.THIS .myUniqueTable th {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. In fact, my font weight attribute stopped working with this code.

Comment: Using `!important` is never the answer